# Basic window creation

Tags: windows, winapi, input, message-queue

I have a problem handling a Windows window, even though I did it this way once before and it worked fine. After reading through the most common suggestions for this problem, it still resides. Could someone tell me why Input-handling is broken?

Intended Behaviour:

1. create a window titled 'FirstTry'
2. Make its background black, using PatBlt
3. Show a message box when the main loop is entered the first time, and after pressing 'w'.
4. Close the window when pressing either Alt+F4, Escape, or the Close-button, displaying a closing message.

Observed behaviour:

1. as intended
2. as intended
3. MessageBox shows up the first time, but is not retriggerable with 'w'
4. Window it not closable, except with TaskManager (one time it showed the 'closing Application'-MessageBox as intended, but only one time)

   - window draggable until the first 'entered loop'-MessageBox is closed, after that its fixed
   - little blue 'busy'-circle of windows10 is shown full-time, after the first MessageBox

Conclusion: The Message-handling is broken.
And i cannot figure out why...

---

System:

- Windows 10, Version 1803 (Build 17134.81), 64-bit

Compiler from VS 2017 Community Edition:

- vcvarsall.bat amd64
- cl -MTd -nologo -FC -Zi -W4 -WX -wd4100 -wd4312 FirstTry.cpp /link User32.lib Gdi32.lib

---

```
#include "windows.h"

static bool bAppIsRunning = false;
static bool bMessageAlreadyShown = false;

LRESULT CALLBACK win_MainWNDCallback(HWND wnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){
    LRESULT result = 0;
    switch(msg){
        case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
        case WM_SYSKEYUP:
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        case WM_KEYUP:{
            WPARAM vKeyCode = wParam;
            bool bWasDown = ((lParam & (1 << 30)) != 0);
            bool bIsDown = ((lParam & (1 << 31)) == 0);
            if (bWasDown != bIsDown)
            {
                switch (vKeyCode)
                {
                    case VK_ESCAPE:{
                        bAppIsRunning = false;
                    }break;
                    default:{
                        result = DefWindowProc(wnd,msg,wParam,lParam);
                    }break;
                }
            }
        }break;
        default:{
            result = DefWindowProc(wnd,msg,wParam,lParam);
        }break;
    }

    return result;
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE HInstance, HINSTANCE HPrevInstance, LPSTR LpCmdLine, int NCmdShow){

    WNDCLASSA wndCLass = {};
    wndCLass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndCLass.lpfnWndProc = win_MainWNDCallback;
    wndCLass.hInstance = HInstance;
    wndCLass.lpszClassName = (LPCSTR)"WindowClass";

    if(RegisterClassA(&wndCLass)){

        HWND wnd = CreateWindowExA(
            0, wndCLass.lpszClassName, (LPCSTR)"FirstTry", 
            WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, 
            CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 
            1240, 720,
            0, 0, HInstance, 0);

        if(wnd){
            bAppIsRunning = true;

            HDC DeviceContext = GetDC(wnd);
            PatBlt(DeviceContext, 0, 0, 1240, 720, BLACKNESS);
            ReleaseDC(wnd, DeviceContext);

            while(bAppIsRunning){

                if(!bMessageAlreadyShown){
                    MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPCSTR)"Successfully entered loop.", (LPCSTR)"Success!", MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_OK);
                    bMessageAlreadyShown = true;
                }

                MSG msg;
                while(PeekMessageA(&msg, 0, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)){
                    switch(msg.message){
                        case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
                        case WM_SYSKEYUP:
                        case WM_KEYDOWN:
                        case WM_KEYUP:{
                            WPARAM vKeyCode = msg.wParam;
                            bool bWasDown = ((msg.lParam & (1<<30)) != 0);
                            bool bIsDown = ((msg.lParam & (1<<31)) != 0);
                            if(bIsDown != bWasDown){
                                switch(vKeyCode){
                                    case 'W':{
                                        bMessageAlreadyShown = false;
                                    }break;
                                    default:{
                                        TranslateMessage(&msg);
                                        DispatchMessageA(&msg);
                                    }break;
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            MessageBoxA(NULL, (LPCSTR)"Closing Application.", (LPCSTR)"Bye bye!", MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_OK);
        }
    }
    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve].

Comment: Why are you building from the command line if you have VS 2017?  Learn to use the IDE and (especially) the debugger.

Comment: @IInspectable I assumed this was the minimum necessary, since it only contains Window-creation, Window-Callback and Message-handling. I'll try to be shorter next time, sorry.

Comment: @PaulSanders I'm using VS Code and its Debugger. VS2017 is a little too heavy for my laptop. Either way it shouldn't matter whether i compile using the IDE and setting the compiler arguments there, or doing it via cmd-line

Comment: Oh, OK, I have never used that so I don't know what it's capable of.  Still, if it has a debugger that works with native C++ I would use it.  There are indications [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging) that it does, or that you can install something that enables it.  I can't stress too highly how important a decent debugger is.  People here will be very reluctant to help you if you don't at least try to get something running on your platform.  Remy went the extra mile there.

Comment: If you are having difficulty handling input, is it *really* necessary for your [mcve] to try and handle more than one keyboard input? Also, this is not a forum. Don't take the advice and wait for the next time you post a question. Fix your question **now**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem with your code is that you are calling `TranslateMessage()` and `DispatchMessage()` only when you receive certain key press messages.  You need to call them in your main message loop for ALL messages instead. And you should be processing ALL of the messages in your WndProc callback.

You are also using `TCHAR`-based APIs, but are misusing `LPCTSTR` typecasts. You need to use the `TEXT()` macro instead when casting string/char literals to `TCHAR`.

Try something more like this instead:

```
#include <windows.h>

static bool bMessageAlreadyShown = false; 

LRESULT CALLBACK win_MainWNDCallback(HWND wnd, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
    switch (msg) {
        case WM_DESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;

        case WM_SYSKEYDOWN:
        case WM_SYSKEYUP:
        case WM_KEYDOWN:
        case WM_KEYUP: {
            WPARAM vKeyCode = wParam;
            bool bWasDown = ((lParam & (1 << 30)) != 0);
            bool bIsDown = ((lParam & (1 << 31)) == 0);
            if (bWasDown != bIsDown) {
                switch (vKeyCode) {
                    case 'W':
                    case VK_ESCAPE:
                        DestroyWindow(wnd);
                        return 0;
                }
            }
            break;
        }

        case WM_ERASEBKGND:
            PatBlt((HDC)wParam, 0, 0, 1240, 720, BLACKNESS);
            return 0;
    }

    return DefWindowProc(wnd, msg, wParam, lParam);;
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE HInstance, HINSTANCE HPrevInstance, LPSTR LpCmdLine, int NCmdShow) {
    WNDCLASS wndCLass = {};
    wndCLass.style = CS_HREDRAW | CS_VREDRAW;
    wndCLass.lpfnWndProc = win_MainWNDCallback;
    wndCLass.hInstance = HInstance;
    wndCLass.lpszClassName = TEXT("WindowClass");

    if (RegisterClass(&wndCLass)) {
        HWND wnd = CreateWindowEx( 0, wndCLass.lpszClassName, TEXT("FirstTry"), WS_OVERLAPPEDWINDOW | WS_VISIBLE, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, 1240, 720, 0, 0, HInstance, 0);
        if (wnd) {
            MSG msg;
            while (GetMessage(&msg, 0, 0, 0)) {
                if (!bMessageAlreadyShown) {
                    bMessageAlreadyShown = true;
                    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Successfully entered loop."), TEXT("Success!"), MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_OK);
                }
                TranslateMessage(&msg);
                DispatchMessage(&msg);
            }
        }
    }

    MessageBox(NULL, TEXT("Closing Application."), TEXT("Bye bye!"), MB_ICONINFORMATION | MB_OK);

    return ERROR_SUCCESS;
}
```

Note that I removed your `bAppIsRunning` variable, as it has  beecome redundant once the message loop processes the `WM_QUIT` message instead.

I also removed handling of <kbd>ALT-F4</kbd>, as the OS handles that for you automatically. It closes the window, triggering a `WM_CLOSE` message. By default, `DefWindowProc()` handles `WM_CLOSE` by destroying the window, which triggers a `WM_DESTROY` message.

I also added handling for `WM_ERASEBKGND` to draw a background on the window. Drawing from outside of the message loop is wrong. As soon as the window needs to be refreshed onscreen, any drawing you do is lost, so you have to redraw everything in response to `WM_ERASEBKGND` and `WM_PAINT`.

Comment: Thanks, I compared mine to yours and realized that I forgot the default case for the switch on PeekMessage. That was the only problem

Comment: The `TEXT` macro and explicit Unicode or ANSI versions of API calls are incompatible.

Comment: @IInspectable I fixed that.

Comment: @Dan `I compared mine to yours...`  Really?  And that's the only difference you can see?  In that case, you need to look again.

Comment: @PaulSanders I am aware of the PostQuitMessage and DestroyWindow calls, and the WM_ERASEBKGND-case and TEXT-macro, as well as not using the specific Ansi-versions of the API-calls... But those were not the reason the window was unresponsive. It works now, and closes without a trace.

Comment: That is not the point.  Remy's message loop and WndProc show how it should be done.  If you haven't grasped that then nothing has been achieved here.